# Will I notice a pressure drop going from 1/2" pex to 3/4" CPVC then to 1/2" CPVC?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, pex

I'm replacing my older CPVC piping in my house and I have access to almost the entire house except the master bath area. At first, I thought it was being fed by a 1/2 inch line that I could just connect into off a Pex manabloc system but it is not.  It is a 3/4 inch line that branches out to 1/2 connections to the shower, sink, and tub except the tub faucet is 3/4.

My question is, if I connect a 1/2 pex to 3/4 CPVC that branches back into 1/2 CPVC about 6 feet later, will I notice a pressure drop or anything?

Answer (score 1):

It truly will not be as efficient as 2 separate lines feeding each fixture, or 3 separate lines for 3 fixtures.... You will only notice a pressure drop when both fixtures on the same branch are used at the same time. You will see the difference, it may not be drastic enough to need to gut what ever is in the way to get it run  everywhere. If I remember right, Maniblock only has 1/2" connectors?

Comment: Correct, Manabloc has only 1/2" connectors. So everything would be, apart from the tub since we are reducing output to 1/2", the same until someone else in the same bathroom turned a fixture on?

Comment: Yes in my experience it would, but only what is on the one branch with the tub, everything else that is fed individually will not be affected. Also just to confirm, depending on your water pressure, although there will be a reduction, it may not be enough to be a concern. It sounds as though there is a portion of the bath you do not wish to demo. Stone or tile that would need to be redone I presume?

Comment: Actually it's nothing major, just drywall, but we just finished the room about 6 months ago. We are going to be replacing the carpet that is in the bathroom so I could get access through the top floor by removing the plywood and connecting it through there. Thanks for your help Jack!